# How to verify Instagram real-time API x-hub-signature in Java?

Tags: java, json, playframework, playframework-2.0, instagram

I'm using Play framework to develop consumer for Instagram real-time API. But still could not perform x-hub-signature verification properly. So, how can we perform Instagram x-hub-signature verification using Java and Play framework?

Here is my current code:

1. From the Play framework, I obtain the JSON payload using this method:

   ```
   public static Result receiveInstaData(){
       JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

       //obtain the x-hub-signature from the header
       //obtain the corresponding client secret

       VerificationResult verificationResult =  
           SubscriptionUtil.verifySubscriptionPostSignature(
               clientSecret, json.toString(), xHubSignature);

       if(verificationResult.isSuccess()){
       //do something
       }
    }
   ```
2. Then inside the `SubscriptionUtil`, I perform verification using this following code:

   ```
   public static VerificationResult verifySubscriptionPostSignature(String clientSecret, String rawJsonData, String xHubSignature) {
       SecretKeySpec keySpec;
       keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes("UTF-8"), HMAC_SHA1);

       Mac mac;
       mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1);
       mac.init(keySpec);

       byte[] result;
       result = mac.doFinal(rawJsonData.getBytes("UTF-8"));
       String encodedResult = Hex.encodeHexString(result);

       return new VerificationResult(encodedResult.equals(xHubSignature), encodedResult);
      }
   ```

I created a standalone Python script that copies the instagram-python implementation and both of them produce the same results for the same `clientSecret` and `jsonString`. Maybe I should provide with raw binary data instead of String.

If let's say we need a raw binary data for JSON request, then I need to create my custom BodyParser to parse the JSON request to raw binary data[5]

References:

[1-4]http://pastebin.com/g4uuDwzn (SO doesn't allow me to post more than 2 links, so I put all the references here. The links contain the signature verification in Ruby, Python and PHP)

[5]https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/play-framework/YMQb6yeDH5o/jU8FD--yVPYJ

[6]My standalone python script:
    #! /usr/bin/env python

```
import sys
import hmac
import hashlib

hc_client_secret = "myclientsecret"
hc_raw_response = "[{\"subscription_id\":\"1\",\"object\":\"user\",\"object_id\":\"1234\",\"changed_aspect\":\"media\",\"time\":1297286541},{\"subscription_id\":\"2\",\"object\":\"tag\",\"object_id\":\"nofilter\",\"changed_aspect\":\"media\",\"time\":1297286541}]"

client_secret = hc_client_secret
raw_response = hc_raw_response

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print 'Usage verify_signature <client_secret> <raw_response>.\nSince the inputs are invalid, use the hardcoded value instead!'
else:
    client_secret = sys.argv[1]
    raw_response = sys.argv[2]  

print "client_secret = " + client_secret
print "raw_response = " + raw_response

digest = hmac.new(client_secret.encode('utf-8'), msg=raw_response.encode('utf-8'), digestmod=hashlib.sha1).hexdigest()
print digest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I managed to find the solution. For the Controller in Play Framework, we need to use `BodyParser.Raw` so the we can extract the payload request as raw data, i.e. array of bytes.

Here's the code for the controller in Play Framework:

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Raw.class)
public static Result receiveRawInstaData(){
    Map<String, String[]> headers = request().headers();
    RawBuffer jsonRaw = request().body().asRaw();

    if(jsonRaw == null){
        logger.warn("jsonRaw is null. Something is wrong with the payload");
        return badRequest("Expecting serializable raw data");
    }

    String[] xHubSignature = headers.get(InstaSubscriptionUtils.HTTP_HEADER_X_HUB_SIGNATURE);
    if(xHubSignature == null){
        logger.error("Invalid POST. It does not contain {} in its header", InstaSubscriptionUtils.HTTP_HEADER_X_HUB_SIGNATURE);
        return badRequest("You are not Instagram!\n");
    }

    String json;
    byte[] jsonRawBytes;

    jsonRawBytes = jsonRaw.asBytes();
    json = new String(jsonRawBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    try {
        String clientSecret = InstaSubscriptionUtils.getClientSecret(1);
        VerificationResult verificationResult = SubscriptionUtil.verifySubscriptionPostRequestSignature
                (clientSecret,jsonRawBytes, xHubSignature[0]);
        if(verificationResult.isSuccess()){
            logger.debug("Signature matches!. Received signature: {}, calculated signature: {}", xHubSignature[0], verificationResult.getCalculatedSignature());
        }else{
            logger.error("Signature doesn't match. Received signature: {}, calculated signature: {}", xHubSignature[0], verificationResult.getCalculatedSignature());
            return badRequest("Signature does not match!\n");
        }
    } catch (InstagramException e) {
        logger.error("Instagram exception.", e);
        return internalServerError("Internal server error. We will attend to this problem ASAP!");
    }

    logger.debug("Received xHubSignature: {}", xHubSignature[0]);
    logger.info("Sucessfully received json data: {}", json);

    return ok("OK!");
}
```

And for the code for method `verifySubscriptionPostRequestSignature` in `SubscriptionUtil`

```
public static VerificationResult verifySubscriptionPostRequestSignature(String clientSecret, byte[] rawJsonData, String xHubSignature) throws InstagramException{
    SecretKeySpec keySpec;
    keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(clientSecret.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8), HMAC_SHA1);
    Mac mac;

    try {
        mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1);
        mac.init(keySpec);
        byte[] result = mac.doFinal(rawJsonData);
        String encodedResult = Hex.encodeHexString(result);

        return new VerificationResult(encodedResult.equals(xHubSignature), encodedResult);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new InstagramException("Invalid algorithm name!", e);
    } catch (InvalidKeyException e){
        throw new InstagramException("Invalid key: " + clientSecret, e);
    }
}
```

I implemented this solution in [jInstagram](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram), here is the link to the source code: [SubscriptionUtil](https://github.com/sachin-handiekar/jInstagram/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jinstagram/realtime/SubscriptionUtil.java#L44)

Comment: One may use     <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
      <version>1.15</version>
    </dependency> for the Hex class. Getting the body as byte[] for the signature checking is key

Answer (score 0):

Important imports:

import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Hex;

import javax.crypto.Mac;

import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

Another simple example:

```
public boolean isValidSignature(byte[] payload, String signature) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {

    signature = signature.replace("sha256=", "");

    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA_256);
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("youSecret".getBytes(), HMAC_SHA_256);
    sha256_HMAC.init(secretKeySpec);

    byte[] hash = sha256_HMAC.doFinal(payload);
    String message = Hex.encodeHexString(hash);
    boolean isValid = message.equals(signature);

    System.out.println(String.format("Signature is valid: %b [payload: %s] [signature: %s]", isValid, new String(payload, Charset.defaultCharset()), signature));
    return isValid;
}
```